# How to unit test scenarios when token must be expired?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, token

I am trying to write unit tests that test AuthenticationService response when given token is expired. The way I do this now - I set expiry date in 1 ms, but this is very unstable. Is there a better way do this?

Here is the code of my unit test method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests service response when refreshing tokens with non-expired refresh token.
/// </summary>
[Fact]
public async void AuthService_UserRefreshesTokens_AuthenticationResponseWithRefreshTokenHasExpiredError()
{
    // Arrange
    _fixture.JwtCfg.TokenLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    _fixture.RefreshTokenCfg.TokenLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    var authResponse = await _fixture.TokenSrvc.GenerateTokenPairForUserAsync(_fixture.Users.First());
    var request = new RefreshTokenRequest
    {
        Token = authResponse.Token,
        RefreshToken = authResponse.RefreshToken
    };
    ((List<RefreshToken>)_fixture.RefreshTokens).Add(new RefreshToken { Token = request.RefreshToken });

    // Act
    var response = await _fixture.AuthSrvc.RefreshTokenAsync(request);

    // Assert
    response.Success.Should().BeFalse();
    response.Errors.Should().ContainSingle();
    response.Errors.ToList()[0].Should().Be("Refresh token has expired, user needs to re-login.");
}
```

With such approach, I get the next error:

```
System.ArgumentException: IDX12401: Expires: 'System.DateTime' must be after NotBefore: 'System.DateTime'.
```

Comment: a JWT can't expire in one ms because the timestamp format (unix epoch time in seconds) has a resolution of one second. Therefore you might get either 0 or 1 second and when it is 0 you get the error which you observed.

Comment: @jps, thanks for the info, but how to test it properly?

Comment: wait before using the token or mock the clock.

Comment: @Ralf, waiting is kinda bad idea. What do you mean by mocking the clock?

Comment: At some point you use DateTime.UtcNow or something like it to initialize the Token and add Timespans to it for its lifetime. When you control what time is delivered in your code (by not using DateTime directly but an interface that can be mocked and arbitrary Datetimes can be returned) you control what is  "now" and can test time dependent code easily.

Comment: @Ralf, could you, please, provide an example of implementation of this concept?

Comment: googled this example https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/04/24/how-to-mock-up-datetime-now-in-unit-tests-using-ambient-context-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

As @Ralf mentioned, the easiest is to delay by 1 sec.

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests service response when refreshing tokens with non-expired refresh token.
/// </summary>
[Fact]
public async void AuthService_UserRefreshesTokens_AuthenticationResponseWithRefreshTokenHasExpiredError()
{
    // Arrange
    _fixture.JwtCfg.TokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _fixture.RefreshTokenCfg.TokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var authResponse = await _fixture.TokenSrvc.GenerateTokenPairForUserAsync(_fixture.Users.First());
    var request = new RefreshTokenRequest
    {
        Token = authResponse.Token,
        RefreshToken = authResponse.RefreshToken
    };
    ((List<RefreshToken>)_fixture.RefreshTokens).Add(new RefreshToken { Token = request.RefreshToken });

    // now wait a little
    await Task.Delay(1001);

    // Act
    var response = await _fixture.AuthSrvc.RefreshTokenAsync(request);

    // Assert
    response.Success.Should().BeFalse();
    response.Errors.Should().ContainSingle();
    response.Errors.ToList()[0].Should().Be("Refresh token has expired, user needs to re-login.");
}
```